# Workaround for projection issue in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We have project where we used projection like this:

```
const filter = { id };
const projection = {
  providers: { $elemMatch: { providerId: ObjectId(providerId) } },
  "providers.payments": 1,
  "providers.tax.vatPayer": 1,
  "providers.tax.vat": 1
}
return super.findOne(filter, projection);
```

As you may know, this is illegal after 4.4. Is there any workaround how to filter specific item in array and then specify which fields of this array to project?

What I've tried:

```
const filter = { id, "providers.providerId": ObjectId(providerId) };
const projection = {
  "providers.$.payments": 1,
  "providers.$.tax.vatPayer": 1,
  "providers.$.tax.vat": 1
}
return super.findOne(filter, projection);
```

```
const filter = { id, "providers.providerId": ObjectId(providerId) };
const projection = {
  "providers.$": 1,
  "providers.payments": 1,
  "providers.tax.vatPayer": 1,
  "providers.tax.vat": 1
}
return super.findOne(filter, projection);
```

```
const filter = { id };
const projection = {
  "providers.$.payments": 1,
  "providers.$.tax.vatPayer": 1,
  "providers.$.tax.vat": 1,
  providers: { $elemMatch: { providerId: ObjectId(providerId) } }
}
return super.findOne(filter, projection);
```

```
const filter = { id };
const projection = {
  providers: {
    $elemMatch: { providerId: ObjectId(providerId) },
    payments: 1,
    "tax.vatPayer": 1,
    "tax.vat": 1
  }
}
return super.findOne(filter, projection);
```

Thanks a lot for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

#### [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) in projection

The `$elemMatch` operator limits the contents of an `<array>` field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the `$elemMatch` condition.

```
return super.findOne(
  { id: id },
  { providers: { $elemMatch: { providerId: ObjectId(providerId) } } }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MyLfYnqK2Cs)

#### [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) projection

The positional `$` operator limits the contents of an `<array>` to return either:

- The first element that matches the query condition on the array.
- The first element if no query condition is specified for the array (Starting in MongoDB 4.4).

> Both the `$` operator and the `$elemMatch` operator project the first matching element from an array based on a condition.

**`$elemMatch` in match condition and `$` projection**

```
return super.findOne(
  { id: id, providers: { $elemMatch: { providerId: ObjectId(providerId) } } },
  { "providers.$": 1 }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iX-IODLL6o_)

**dot`(.)` notation in match condition and `$` projection**

```
return super.findOne(
  { id: id, "providers.providerId": ObjectId(providerId) },
  { "providers.$": 1 }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-EFaYQJeOhB)

**Positional Operator Placement Restriction [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#positional-operator-placement-restriction)**:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, the `$` projection operator can only appear at the end of the field path; e.g. `"field.$"` or `"fieldA.fieldB.$"`.

**Positional Operator and `$slice` Restriction [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#positional-operator-and-slice-restriction)**:

> Starting in MongoDB 4.4, `find` and `findAndModify` projection cannot include `$slice` projection expression as part of a `$` projection expression.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not an answer, this is just explanation which I already now... I was looking if there is some workaround to use in 4.4 which I might overlook, the examples I posted was just tries from despair... It's IOT project, and we wanted to save as much data as we could and this is big nono for us, because we used that syntax on many places

Comment: actually i explained all of the possibilities, your tries is not possible as i provided restrictions at the end of my answer, i have added all possible workaround of `$` and `$elemMatch` for projection. if you know all these then i am not sure what are you looking for. if you know there is no way then this kind of questions are meaningless.

Comment: Your question is consider as off-topic i would suggest you to improve your question with proper problem and if you know already about find's projection and your tries are not possible then this question is meaningless, If you are looking for other possibilities using other aggregation operators i would suggest you to refer aggregation `$project` stage, directly they have provided all the possibilities of `$project` in find()'s projection from v4.4.